# Registration not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The registration process ends with the redirection but the user doesn't get added to the database. I tried everything and can't see the issue. If you need anything ask and I'll edit this post with the content or explanation.

```
<?php 
$cookie="tD2h6";

$jucatoru = $_POST['numeleluii'];
$passw = $_POST['pass'];
$email = $_POST['mail'];

$con=mysqli_connect("xx","xx","xxx","xx");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$jucatoru = $con->real_escape_string($jucatoru);
$passw = $con->real_escape_string($passw);
$email = $con->real_escape_string($email);

if(strlen($jucatoru)>1)
{
    $crypt = md5($passw);
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `users` (username,password,mail) VALUES ($jucatoru,$crypt,$email);");
    $data = "name=" . $jucatoru . "&pass=" . md5($passw);
    setcookie ( $cookie, $data, time()+60*60*24 );
    header("Location: http://r4ge.ro");
    die;
}



echo "<div class=\"box box-info\">
    <i class=\"ion-locked\"></i>
    <h3 class=\"box-title\">Register</h3>
    </div>


    <form action=\"/php/register.php\" method=\"post\">
    <div class=\"form-group\">
    <input class=\"form-control\" type=\"text\" name=\"numeleluii\" value=\"\"  placeholder=\"Username:\"/><br />
    </div>
    <div class=\"form-group\">
    <input class=\"form-control\" type=\"email\" name=\"mail\" value=\"\"  placeholder=\"e-mail: example@domain.tdl\"/><br />
    </div>
    <div class=\"form-group\">
    <input class=\"form-control\" type=\"password\" name=\"pass\" value=\"\"placeholder=\"Password:\" /><br />
    </div>

    <div class=\"box-footer clearfix\">
        <input class=\"pull-right btn btn-default\" type=\"submit\" name=\"send\" value=\"Send\" />
    </div>
      </form>

      </div>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Please don't use md5 for storing passwords, you may as well be storing them in plaintext for all the good it does. Also, escaping POST input does NOT prevent injection - use parametrised queries instead.

Comment: This is just begging for an SQL Injection. Either way, the query's wrong. It should be `"INSERT INTO users(username, password, mail) VALUES ('$jucatoru', '$crypt', '$email')";`

Comment: You don't need the `;` on the end of your query. You should also wrap your variables in single quotes in the query.  You should check the return value of `mysqli_query()` for an error and look at `mysqli_error()` if you find one. (Why do so many people omit basic error checking?)

Comment: thank you, your query worked. another question is why am I begging for a sql injection, @AndreiP. ? is real_escape_string not the correct way to prevent this nowadays? edit:: I just saw first comment

Comment: Aron, real_escape_string has never prevented injection - that's a myth.

Comment: @Aron H. Side note: You from Romania? Answer. No, it really doesn't. Not as much as you think. I suggest looking up prepared statements. And maybe(this is personal preference) try using PDO instead of mysqli. Although both are ok APIs.

Comment: @AndreiP. yes I am. Please stick around this page guys, I'll have a look at parametrised queries since I used them before, I need a review

Comment: @AronH. Throw me a PM instead of posting questions for trivial things. I'll give you a hand.

Comment: @AndreiP. I can't find PM on this site, I've always had a hard time getting around. I only know the chat function which I don't know how to start except spam in comments till the button appears. Any help? or maybe some contact info like skype or y!m?

Comment: @Aron sure add me: andrei.popa1988 on skype. Forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax error.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `users` (username,password,mail) VALUES ($jucatoru,$crypt,$email)");
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a better implementation of your code, using php prepared statements.

```
<?php 
$cookie="tD2h6";

$jucatoru = $_POST['numeleluii'];
$passw = $_POST['pass'];
$email = $_POST['mail'];

if(!empty($jucatoru)){
    $conn = new mysqli("xx", "xx", "xx", "xx");
    $conn->set_charset("utf8");

    if ($conn->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $conn->connect_errno . ") " . $conn->connect_error;
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (username,password,mail) VALUES (?,?,?)";
    if($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)){
        $crypt = md5($passw)
        $stmt->bind_param('sss', $jucatoru, $passw, $crypt);
        $stmt->execute();

        $data = "name=" . $jucatoru . "&pass=" . md5($passw);
        setcookie($cookie, $data, time()+60*60*24 ;
        header("Location: http://r4ge.ro");
        exit();
    }else{
        echo $conn->error;
    }
}

............

?>
```

Comment: Don't forget to `exit();` after the redirect.

Comment: thank you very much @maxinuss . If you still see this, could you explain $stmt->bind_param('sss', $jucatoru, $passw, $crypt);, the 'sss' part? what's that for?

Answer (score 4):

```
if(strlen($jucatoru)>1){
    $crypt = md5($passw);
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `users` (username,password,mail) VALUES ('{$jucatoru}','{$crypt}','{$email}')");
    if($result){
        echo "Data inserted";
    }else{
        echo "Error in inserting";
    }
    $data = "name=" . $jucatoru . "&pass=" . md5($passw);
    setcookie ( $cookie, $data, time()+60*60*24 );
    header("Location: http://r4ge.ro");
    die;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think `{` and `}` are required?

Comment: in insert query { is not that much important compared to ' but adding { put as in a safer place to insert a specific value in that field name